# Order values in existing table in alphabetical order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have table StateList with all state names. To the COL Name, I later added "Michigan" that is always at the bottom of list in a dropdown table. What is the easiest way to alphabetize column Name without dropping table as it has FK constraints.

I have tried this:

```
Select Name From StateList
Order By Name ASC
```

That displays alphabetically for the result, but when I Select * From StateList again, the column is still original order with Michigan at bottom. Do i need to re-insert all my state values?

Comment: Records in a table have no order. When you don't use ORDER BY, The order they get returned is whatever order is convenient for SQL at that time.

Comment: It is easier to delete the Michigan name value and re-insert it after "Massachusetts"? Everything else is alphabetized. For example: Insert into Statelist(Name) Values("Michigan") after Massachusetts? But how?

Comment: It is easier to do nothing, but that also will not work.  @JNK has the correct answer below, it is the only thing that will work reliably.  When you don't use `ORDER BY` you are telling SQL "*I don't care what order you return the records.*", and SQL beleives you and does whatever it wants.  Just because it has been returning them in the same order so far, doesn't mean it will in the future.  If you ***want*** a specific order, then you ***need*** to tell it so.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `ORDER` without an `ORDER BY`.  The order you inserted records into the table has no predictable relationship to the order they are retrieved.  Without a `JOIN` or other filter on the results, they **probably** come back in `INSERT` order, but there's no guarantee.

If you want to get results back in a specific order, use `ORDER BY`.  Period.